# Calling a function within ReReplace function

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a way to write in coldfusion something like:

```
< cfset ReReplace(value,"&#\d+;","#decodeHtmlEntity(\1)#", "all") >
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Based on the ongoing discussion, this is obviously version=-dependent.  What version of CF are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No".

CF doesn't handle the regular expression execution natively.  It hands off to a Java library (Oro, IIRC) to handle that.  This means that any CF functions you call get executed *before* toe regex.

There is a workaround, although it's not nearly as elegant as being able to pass functions would be.  Use reFind() to discover all the instances of what you are looking for, and repolace them one-by-one. If you do the replaces last-to-first (eg if there are 3 instances, do the 3rd, then the 2nd, then the 1st) your starting point for each match will remain in the same location, so you can do an reFind all, instead of doing the reFind in the loop.

HTH.

Comment: While it is correct that CF hands off to java for pretty much all of its functionality, the rest of this statement is incorrect. Please see my response below for a working and tested solution.

Comment: In which version did you test successfully?  I can check 9 when I get home tonight, but it doesn't work in 6.1 (what is used where I work) and I remember it as not working correctly in 7 or 8....

Comment: admittedly it was against 9.0.1 I'll confirm it against 8 tomorrow. re: cfmx 6.1 - yikes! you need help!

Comment: Heh.  Running 6.1 isn't my idea.  But it could be worse -- we could be on 5.  :-)

Comment: This is literally the only way I can think of to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work if you want to replace regular expression value as argument of decodeHTMLEntity.

Updated:

```
   <cfset myVar = ReReplace("ABC123DEF","(\d+)",addOne('\1'), "all") >
   <cffunction name="addOne" access="public" output="false" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="arg1" required="true" type="string" />
    <cfreturn arg1 + 1>
</cffunction>
<cfdump var="#myvar#">
```

Above code written to find 123 from text and add one into it but this will not work as arg1 will have \1 which is not numeric value.

Comment: You can wrap a back reference from the regex in a function in the "replace with" attribute. See my working answer.

Comment: @Stephen, When you call urlDecode('\1') it will pass \1 as argument value not regular expression calculated value. For better explanation see below code.
`code`
<cfset myVar = ReReplace("ABC123DEF","(\d+)",addOne('\1'), "all") >
<cffunction name="addOne" access="public" output="false" returntype="string">
<cfargument name="arg1" required="true" type="string" />
 <cfreturn arg1 + 1>
</cffunction>
<cfdump var="#myvar#">
`code`
Here I just want to find out digit from given string add one into it but this will not work as in function "ADDONE" you will receive \1 as arg1 not 123.

Comment: ok so it would seem that my working code below is only working in ColdFusion 9. I haven't tried it in any of the other engines.

Comment: No, I have tested in CF9 as well and it will not work. But your code will work as urlDecode function accept string and process on string but in your case urlDecode function will return \1 which is later replace by REREPLACE function.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried simply using URLDecode(value)?

Or if you specifically only want to decode the numeric html codes, then

```
<cfset myVar = ReReplace(value,"(&##[\d+];)",urlDecode('\1'), "all") >
```

will do what you need.

To explain what it is doing :

- I've replaced the PHP decodeHTMLEntity function with the CFML version.
- If you want to use back references you need to specify the capture groups in the regex pattern.
- you need to double up those #'s to escape them, otherwise CF will be looking for a close # that it will never find.

Comment: The urlDecode method you are using there will only run on the string "\1", it will not be applied to the found values.